# MySQL not getting query, not displaying any errors

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to run a MySQL query, but for some reason its not working.

This is the query im running:

```
SELECT * FROM applications WHERE status = 0
```

And my database looks like this:
http://gyazo.com/cc0bfa109e73a771d99a22b5051ee2de

However, num_rows() returns 0 rows...

No errors are displayed...

Comment: Please show your PHP code.

Comment: How are you calling this sql?

Comment: sounds like all rows in `applications` have a status of something other than `0`.

Comment: have you tried `SELECT * FROM applications WHERE status = '0'`

Comment: You need to post your schema. `status` might be `" 0 "` or something irregular. A screen-shot is not especially helpful. What you should add is the `SHOW CREATE TABLE applications` output.

Comment: the status field is a enum field, `enum('0', '1', '2')`.

The PHP section is:
`$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM applications WHERE status = 0');`
`echo $query->num_rows();`

Im using code igniter btw

Comment: @Jeff - Tried your suggestion, and it seemed to work. Still dont understand, because I've done it without them alot... Weired, anyway, thanks  
@tadman - How do I add that `SHOW CREATE TABLE applications`... In my PHP or as a SQL in PMA?

Comment: your enum lists '0', '1', '2' - not 0, 1, 2 - hence why you need to use the single quotes in your query.

Comment: quick comment.  Enums are great because the let you use human readable values but store integers behind the scenes - takes up less space in the db.  so why not actually use ENUM('Pending', etc).  also in the screen shot your numbers are left aligned showing clearly that they are text, numeric fields like the ids are right aligned in phpmyadmin.

Comment: As a note, `ENUM` columns are really annoying and are best avoided. If you need to change the definition of a column you'll need to rebuild the entire table, and on any table of non-trivial size, this gets expensive fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope it will help you because i have tested in localhost.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM applications WHERE status = 0";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['mcUser'];
}
```

IF its not work's check your table name again.

Answer (score 0):

replace the query with single quotes between 0
$sql = "SELECT * FROM applications WHERE status = '0'";